# Ruby on Windows: `ansi.rb` get_screen_size error: in `winsize': Bad file descriptor - <STDIN> (Errno::EBADF)

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to use fastlane on Windows, which is installed from Bundler -- which is installed by Ruby Gem. But while running, some internal error of Ruby seems blocked the execution.

First, I went to [Ruby Installer](https://rubyinstaller.org/) and installed `Ruby+Devkit 3.0.2-1 (x64)`; then, I installed the Bundler and Fastlane using `gem` command. Error below happened when I was trying to execute them -- which I believed was not related to Bundler nor Fastlane:

```
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/ansi.rb:157:in `winsize': Bad file descriptor - <STDIN> (Errno::EBADF)
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline/ansi.rb:157:in `get_screen_size'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/reline.rb:168:in `get_screen_size'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `get_screen_size'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tty-screen-0.8.1/lib/tty/screen.rb:236:in `size_from_readline'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tty-screen-0.8.1/lib/tty/screen.rb:66:in `size'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/tty-screen-0.8.1/lib/tty/screen.rb:76:in `width'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/print_table.rb:95:in `transform_output'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/plugins/plugin_manager.rb:335:in `print_plugin_information'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/plugins/plugin_manager.rb:316:in `load_plugins'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:39:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:122:in `take_off'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.197.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Windows 10 home version `20H2`.

Rebooting the computer doesn't solve the problem.

I tried googling the question, but it seems that problem hasn't be reported (or be answered). I don't know where I can report the bug either.

What can I do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _when I was trying to execute them_  : Perhaps it would be a good idea to also post all commands which you have executed.

Comment: That command was just one line, `bundle exec fastlane`, or even `fastlane`, which causes the problem. But after took a look into what error says, I doubt that the error has nothing to do with my command, nor the fastlane/bundler...?

Comment: Have you tried to install ruby 2.7.0
https://rubyinstaller.org/2020/01/05/rubyinstaller-2.7.0-1-released.html

Comment: @NemanjaFilipovic huh, I'm using ruby 3.0.0, so downgrading might could solve my problem? I'll take a try if I have spare time. But no matter what, downgrading might not be a perfect/final solution, so I'll keep the question open.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with both  Ruby+Devkit 2.7.5-1 (x64) and Ruby+Devkit 3.0.3-1 (x64). I only tried to run `bundle exec fastlane actions`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when I tried running `bundle exec fastlane` in git bash.
I got it working by running it in powershell instead.